# PHP - how to retrieve value of input type file on Ajax / JQuery page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can retrieve input type text, textarea, select on Ajax / JQuery page. Then variable values are passed to PHP process page where data are retrieve using POST method and data inserted into database table. All things are working fine.

But when I try to retrieve value of input type file variable on Ajax / Query page, it is giving blank value. I tried different codes to do it which I found from internet.

Please advise so I can make necessary changes in my script to make it working.

**personal_details.php**

```
<form name="AddForm" id="AddForm" novalidate>
<div class="control-group form-group">
    .
    .
    <input type="file" name="file_photo" id="file_photo">
    .
    .
    other fields like Name, Mail etc
    .
    .
    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**personal_details.js**

```
$(function() {

$("#AddForm input,#AddForm textarea, #AddForm file").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        .
        .
        var file_photo = $("file#file_photo").val();
        //var file_photo = $('#file_photo')[0].files[0];
        //var file_photo = document.getElementById("file_photo").files[0];

        $.ajax({
            url: "./user/personal_details_p.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                file_photo: file_photo,
            },
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) 
            {
                //alert(data);
                var $ResponseText_L=JSON.parse(data);
                .
                .
                if condition
                .
                .
            },
        })
    },
});
```

**personal_details_p.php**

```
$str_name = "";
if (isset($_POST["name"])) { $str_name = trim($_POST["name"]); }
$str_email = "";
if (isset($_POST["email"])) { $str_email = trim($_POST["email"]); }
$str_photo = "";
if(isset($_FILES['file_photo'])) { $str_photo = trim($_FILES['file_photo']['name']); }

.
.
SQL Query to insert data
.
.

$response['status']='SUC';
$response['message']="Data inserted successfully";
echo json_encode($response);
return;
```

Comment: You cannot simply upload `file` through AJAX using input's value. Look here to upload file via AJAX : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easy Ajax Image Upload with jQuery, PHP](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/12/easy-ajax-image-upload-with-jquery-php.html)

All textbox, textarea and file type variables will be available on PHP process page with the same name like they have on HTML form page.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing file you should have to do like this in jquery:

```
 $(function() {

$("#AddForm input,#AddForm textarea, #AddForm file").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
         var file_data = $("#file_photo").prop("files")[0];

    var form_data = new FormData();

            form_data.append("doc_upload", file_data)
            var data_text=$('form').serializeArray();
            $.each(data_text,function(key,input){
                form_data.append(input.name,input.value);
            });
        $.ajax({
            url: "./user/personal_details_p.php",
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
            data: form_data,  
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) 
            {
                //alert(data);
                var $ResponseText_L=JSON.parse(data);
                .
                .
                if condition
                .
                .
            },
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: After using above piece of code, I am not able to click on submit button now. Please advise.

Comment: then you have to pass for form_data to data please check answer i just edit it i hope you will get some idea

Comment: Ty... page is not submitted when I keep this code 'data: form_data,' on page ... Please advise about this.

Comment: Please check in firefox console and let me know error

Comment: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Check by putting this your browser is supporting or not if (! window.FormData) {　
        alert ( 'your brower is too old');
        return false;
    }

Comment: Or you can also check by using this  var form_data = new FormData($("#file_photo").prop("files")[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own function for asynchronous upload with progress bar. I will try to write example for you. Also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form.

```
var file_photo = $("file#file_photo").val();
var form = file_photo.parents('form');
file_photo.on('change', processUpload);

var processUpload = function() {
    var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "./user/personal_details_p.php",
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

            if(myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandling, false);
            }

            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(json) {
            file_photo.val(''); // Empty file input after upload
        },
        error: function() {
            // Do whatever you want as error message
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
};

var progressHandling = function(e) {
    if(e.lengthComputable) {
        // Uploaded bytes: e.loaded / Maximum bytes: e.total
    }
};
```

Comment: Ty, I will try this and will let you know result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. It has various options and its documentation is also good. so if you can use plugin you can go with this

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code for file upload.

```
   $(function() {

    $("#AddForm input,#AddForm textarea, #AddForm file").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();

            // my edit for File upload code starts here

             var FileData = $('#file_photo').prop('files')[0];   
             var form_data = new FormData();                  
             form_data.append('file', FileData);

           // my edit for File upload code ends here             

            $.ajax({
                url: "./user/personal_details_p.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    file_photo: file_photo,
                },
                cache: false,

                success: function(data) 
                {
                    //alert(data);
                    var $ResponseText_L=JSON.parse(data);
                    .
                    .
                    if condition
                    .
                    .
                },
            })
        },
    });
```

Comment: Ty for your answer, page is not submitted when I keep this code 'file_photo: file_photo,' ... Please advise about this.